# this.template.querySelector works in parent template but not child template

Tags: lightning-web-components, data, queryselector

I'm using the following in Javascript functions in LWC  "var uiSection = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="sidebar"]');"  to find a UI element with data-id=sidebar. This works ok when  exists within the same  in the LWC.  However if I call "var uiSection = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="sidebar"]');" from an onclick in a child  it can't find it.  The following is a pseudocode of my code

Markup

```
                    <div class="expander active" data-id="expander-control" onclick={divClickHandler} ></div>
                    <ul class="sidebar" data-id="sidebar">
                        <template for:each={stations} for:item="station">
                            <li class="active stationItem" key={station}>
                                <div class="item-header">
                                    <div class="label">{station.Name}</div >
                                </div>  
                                <template if:true={station.Station_Assets__r}>
                                    <div class="item-content">
                                        <template for:each={station.Station_Assets__r} for:item="asset">
                                            <ul class="typelist" style="max-height: 156px;" key={asset.Id} onclick={assetClickHandler}>
                                                <li>
                                                    <span key={asset.Id} id={asset.Id} data-id={asset.Id} class="assetType" data-classname="assetType" onclick={assetClickHandler}>{asset.Name}</span>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </template>     
                                    </div>    
                                </template>   
                            </li>
                        </template>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

JS Functions

```
divClickHandler(event, component) {
    var uiSection = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="sidebar"]');
    if(uiSection){
        console.log('Found section');
    }else{
        console.log('Not Found');
    }
 }  

assetClickHandler(event, component) {

    var uiSection = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="sidebar"]');
    if(uiSection){
        console.log('Found section from asset');
    }else{
        console.log('Not Found from asset');
    }
}
```

...

My call to divClickHandler finds the UI with the data-id ok.  My call to assetClickHandler does not find it.  Should this.template.querySelector not work across the whole DOM or does it only work in the immediate template?
To access the same UI element in a child  what would be the best way to do this?  Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. LWC uses shadow DOM and so one component cannot see the DOM for another. This is by design. You can read more in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom).

Answer (score 0):

`this.template.querySelector` will only access the DOM that the component owns, excluding children component(s) due to the nature of shadow DOM.

however, for nested templates with template directives, you should be able to access the dom with selectors, as you are doing.

I did a quick copy pasta version f your code, I am unable to reproduce what you are experiencing, maybe you can update it and share a link in your post with the issue?

[Your component in Web.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/AUVEHh228kXfkXbu1eD7)

Comment: Hi @phil w and glls, thank you for your help. One thing I may have mis-explained  is that the markup is all in one component. There is no child component. What I meant was there are different layers of <template> within the component.  By child I meant there are <template>'s within <template>.  Does the same logic apply in terms of shadow DOM for nested <template>'s also as opposed to nested components?  Maybe the same issue applies?   Thanks again for your help.

Comment: if the templates, are just nested templates within the same component, the DOM should be accessible iirc, as it is owned by the same component. If you have a template directive that prevents rendering of certain sections based on x conditions, that might be the actual issue.

Comment: No. The `template` elements are not separate DOMs. Have you tried adding the "ul" element to the query selector, or even the .sidebar class, rather than having just the unadorned attribute selector?

Comment: It is true that if the element is not shown due to an if:true/false expression then it does not get rendered to the DOM and you will get undefined.

Comment: @RedQueries - shared a link for you in the post. feel free to update and share in your post